# Ruby - pass in value from ActiveRecord query to javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby, activerecord

I am new to Ruby on Rails and Active record and am having difficulty passing in a value from an ActiveRecord query to javascript to update a textfield whenever a user changes their selection on a dropdown list.

Here is the relevant code which is not working:

```
var tableDesc  = $(".dropdown_selector").val();

var tableId = "#{EntityName.where(id:" + tableDesc.to_i + ").pluck(:code)}";

$(".textField").text("#{get_table_value('" + tableId + "')}");
```

There is no error as such but the tableId value is empty whenever I output using console.log()

Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: In Rails, Ruby is only executed server-side, conversely javascript is client side. They can't be executed within the same file simulateneously. You'll need to use AJAX to send your javascript variables as parameters to your controller, which can respond with javascript.

Comment: Okay that's what I thought - but wasn't sure if there was another solution other than an AJAX call. Thanks for your speedy response! : )